# org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.EJBComponentUnavailableException: JBAS014559: Invocation cannot proceed as component is shutting down

Tags: jboss, seam

I am getting below error in Stateful session bean

```
13:27:38,842 WARN  [org.jboss.seam.Component] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) Exception calling stateful session bean default @Remove method: : org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.EJBComponentUnavailableException: JBAS014559: Invocation cannot proceed as component is shutting down
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50) [jboss-as-ee-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:55) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45) [jboss-as-ee-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165) [jboss-as-ee-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:182) [jboss-as-ee-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.stateful.StatefulComponentIdInterceptor.processInvocation(StatefulComponentIdInterceptor.java:52) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61) [jboss-invocation-1.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:72) [jboss-as-ee-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at us.tx.state.twc.twist.claim.session.Payment$$$view24.cleanup(Unknown Source) [Twist-ejb.jar:]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor742.invoke(Unknown Source) [:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInvocationContext.proceed(RootInvocationContext.java:32) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.ClientSideInterceptor$1.proceed(ClientSideInterceptor.java:76) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:56) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.ejb.RemoveInterceptor.aroundInvoke(RemoveInterceptor.java:43) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.core.SynchronizationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SynchronizationInterceptor.java:32) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.SeamInvocationContext.proceed(SeamInvocationContext.java:68) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.RootInterceptor.invoke(RootInterceptor.java:107) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.intercept.ClientSideInterceptor.invoke(ClientSideInterceptor.java:54) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.javassist.tmp.java.lang.Object_$$_javassist_seam_14.cleanup(Object_$$_javassist_seam_14.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invoke(Reflections.java:22) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.util.Reflections.invokeAndWrap(Reflections.java:144) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.callComponentMethod(Component.java:2249) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.callDefaultRemoveMethod(Component.java:2154) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.destroy(Component.java:1479) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts.destroy(Contexts.java:251) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.contexts.Lifecycle.endSession(Lifecycle.java:295) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.contexts.ServletLifecycle.endSession(ServletLifecycle.java:160) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener.sessionDestroyed(SeamListener.java:59) [jboss-seam.jar:2.2.0.GA]
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.expire(StandardSession.java:681) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.expire(StandardSession.java:644) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:644) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:3916) [jbossweb-7.2.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStop(WebDeploymentService.java:171) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$100(WebDeploymentService.java:60) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$2.run(WebDeploymentService.java:113) [jboss-as-web-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.6.0_31]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
```

I have stateful session bean with  @Destroy     public void destroy() {     }       //if a method with the @Remove is invoked the bean is destroyed after the method complete       @Remove     public void cleanup() {     }   , during server stop getting above error

```
@Stateful
@Transactional
@Name("claim")
@JndiName(value="java:app/abc-ejb/ClaimAction")
@Scope(ScopeType.SESSION)
@Synchronized(timeout=100000000)
@Install(precedence = Install.FRAMEWORK+6)
public class ClaimAction extends implements Claim { 
    @Destroy
    public void destroy() {-----
    }   
    //if a method with the @Remove is invoked the bean is destroyed after    the method complete    
   @Remove
   public void cleanup() {----
   }
}
During server stop getting above error
```

Comment: Add more details about your problem.

Comment: I have stateful session bean with